Typescript type arguments placeholder doesn't work
In Typescript 5.2 were added type arguments placeholders. That is, if you have something like
declare function f<A, B, C>(x: A, y: B, z: C): C

You can write f<_, _, 1>("",[],1) to specify you expect C to be 1 (it would else be inferred as number), but you let the compiler infer A and B.
I have Typescript 5.5, but when I write the above, I get an error : Cannot find name '_'.
Any idea what's going on ?

"In Typescript 5.2 were added type arguments placeholders." No, what makes you think that? It's not mentioned in the release notes. Maybe you saw they they would investigate it in the iteration plan (ms/TS#54298) but that's a far cry from releasing anything. The relevant pull request at ms/TS#26349 has not been merged. It's not a TS feature. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll answer.

Yeah it does. I kind of lived in a parallel dimension where it had been released - due to this article, in particular : https://www.totaltypescript.com/type-argument-placeholders-typescript-5-2-most-discussed-feature -, but, well. Thanks !

Type argument placeholders don't work because the feature has not been released (as of TypeScript 5.6).
There is nothing about that feature mentioned in the TypeScript 5.2 release notes.  The pull request implementing type argument placeholders, microsoft/TypeScript#26349, has not been merged.
There was some investigation into releasing that feature with TypeScript 5.2, as mentioned in the TypeScript 5.2 iteration plan, and indeed in the 2023-05-05 Design Meeting Notes it was mentioned that they wanted to try releasing the feature in TypeScript 5.2.  But, in the 2023-05-10 Design Meeting Notes, it was mentioned that "changing overload resolution broke a ton, so we backed off of the 'partial type argument' thing." Meaning, presumably, they've decided not to push forward with this feature until they can resolve issues with it.
So it's not part of the language, and that explains why you can't use it.
